# C++ Unordered map initializer map not initializing properly

Tags: c++, hashmap

I'm relatively new to hash maps. I have the following code in my program:

```
    std::unordered_map<int, int> XY ({
        {0, 0}, {0, 3}, {0, 6},
        {3, 0}, {3, 3}, {3, 6},
        {6, 0}, {6, 3}, {6, 6}
    });
```

For some reason, the map only contains the first three pairs ({0, 0}, {0, 3}, and {0, 6}). Even when I `cout` the bucket count, it outputs 11. Yet, there's still only three in my map.
How do I fix this? It seems unreasonable to do a bunch of .insert()'s.

Comment: It shouldn't have `0, 0`, `0, 3` and `0, 6`; `std::unordered_map` has unique keys, so it can't have the key `0` three times. If you want to allow the same key to map to multiple values, you need `std::unordered_multimap`. Also, the bucket count doesn't mean what you seem to think it means; it means how many buckets *exist*, not how many are filled; it's normal for `.bucket_count()` to exceed `.size()` (IIRC, the default `load_factor` is `1`, so you'd only see the size and bucket count equal for a moment; the next insertion would expand the bucket count well beyond the size).

Comment: Ah, right. Thank you. I suppose I'll switch to either a multimap, or a 2D array.